# Qlikview - subtract one year

Tags: qlikview

I want in text box to do next:

```
Today() - one year
```

and get

Today = 20.9.2016

Past = 20.9.2015

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AddMonths()` function and add -12 months:

```
Today()                   // result: 20/09/2016
AddMonths( Today(), -12 ) // result: 20/09/2015
```

More about `AddMonths()` function you can read [here](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.0/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/DateAndTimeFunctions/addmonths.htm)

Answer (score 3):

just use [AddYears(startdate, n)](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.0/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/DateAndTimeFunctions/addyears.htm)